# cordova.file.externalRootDirectory not working in Android 11 devices

Tags: android, cordova

**I not able to download file in android 11 version devices.**

```
**Details :**

cordova android 10.1.0        
"cordova-plugin-file" version="6.0.2"           
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer" version="1.7.1"           
"cordova-plugin-filepath" version="1.6.0"   

**My Code:**
```

Below code I written to download files device its working in android 9 and 10 , when I target SDK 30 its not working and failing in only android 11.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function(dir) {
    dir.getFile("test.pdf", {create:true}, function(file) {
        file.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
        fileWriter.write("byteArrays data");
            alert('Message', 'File Downloaded Successfully');
        }, function(){
            alert('Error!', "Unable to save the file");
        });
    },function(e){
        alert('Error!', e);
    });
},function(e){
    console.log(e);
});

**I tried with below code in Androidmainfest file**

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>



**Config.xml file**
<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

Please let me know if anything is missing , **Thank you in advance.**

Comment: Yes. You did not tell full path of the file you try to create. And with 'not working' you did not give a problem description.

Comment: @blackapps taking base64 data and converting into pdf using **new Blob** and saving into device. let me know if any solution. trying from last days nthg worked but same code is working in android 9 and 10.

Comment: Repeat: You did not tell full path of the file you try to create.

Comment: @blackapps my system path is  - /storage/emulated/0/

Answer (score 6):

I've found that the `downloadFile` method of the plugin [Cordova Advanced HTTP](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http#downloadFile) is a great way to download files. I created this [example app](https://github.com/alex-steinberg/android11-cordova-file-issues) to show how it can work.

Note that the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission has [essentially been deprecated](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) in Android 11 so you can no longer download to shared storage (e.g. `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` which is shared by many apps -- a privacy and security risk). Try one of the directories scoped to your app such as `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory`.

Comment: I need to save an image file to external storage (in the **Pictures** directory for example) so it appears in the gallery. 
Saving to `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory` works, but it won't be shown in gallery...
For now I'm using the `requestLegacyExternalStorage=true` but it will be ignore by Android 11.
I Tried to use `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing` but sadly it doesn't show a "save file" option anymore.
Is there another way to keep saving pictures in the **Pictures** directory?

Comment: @E-telier this requires the new [MediaStore API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) and there isn't a Cordova solution for this that I'm aware of. I found this [Capacitor plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@agorapulse/capacitor-mediastore) which you could use once you decide to migrate from Cordova...

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know about MediaStore. I found a Cordova plugin using it : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-mediastore

Answer (score 0):

On an Android 11+ device one cannot create files anymore in root of external storage (/storage/emulated/0).

Use an excisting public directory like DCIM, Pictures, Documents,.. there.

Comment: please can you share code , it will be more helpfull

Comment: Sorry, i do not use Cordova.